# How to test for a raised Exception in the exit of a context manager?

Tags: python, pytest

I am using pytest to test my program. I want to test for an Exception of type `Foo` being raised when a context manager exits. Using

```
with pytest.raises(Foo):
  with my_context_mngr():
    pass
```

works but with the caveat that it will silently succeed if `Foo` is raised during the initialization of the context manager, which, as it turns out, could be the case.

Is there a way to handle this situation with `pytest` other than having to call the context managers methods directly?

Comment: I would recommend just adding a separate test that validates the context manager instantiates without errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a flag inside the `with` body, and test it afterward:

```
enter_succeeded = False

with pytest.raises(Foo):
  with my_context_mngr():
    enter_succeeded = True

assert enter_succeeded
```

If the flag is unset, then an exception occurred in `__enter__`.

Answer (score 0):

The [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#typecontextmanager) statement is simply syntactic sugar for calling the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods before and after the statement body, respectively, so to test specifically the exit of a context manager, you can make explicit calls to the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods instead of using the `with` statement:

```
import sys

context_manager = my_context_mngr()
context = context_manager.__enter__()
try:
    ... # body of the with statement; do something with context
except Exception:
    with pytest.raises(Foo):
        if not context_manager.__exit__(*sys.exc_info()):
            raise
else:
    with pytest.raises(Foo):
        context_manager.__exit__(None, None, None)
```

Comment: This does the wrong thing with exceptions raised inside the `try`. If the body of the `try` doesn't raise an exception, the `raise` can end up trying to re-raise a non-existent exception. On the other hand, if the body of the `try` *does* raise an exception, `finally` can't suppress that exception, regardless of what `__exit__` returns - you need an `except` block for that.

Comment: Right. I've rolled back to my initial version. Was needlessly trying to simplify the code with a function.